# How to change the text color of the row when it is highlighted in jquery jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with multi select. When i select any row the background is getting changed but the color of that text is not changing. Can anyone help me to solve this please.

```
.ui-jqgrid-btable .ui-state-highlight 
{
    background : #72A0C1;
    color : white;
 }
```

Comment: Yes.. But I didn't get the result

Comment: You should use the inspector tools of your browser to check whether your color proberty is overriden by something. Try `color: white !important;`. However this is no clean solution and you should only use it as a test.

Comment: Yea i have already tried with that . But its not working

Comment: As Rico mentioned you need to find out(using dev tool) if and which css rule is overriding your above color declaration. After that you can use a different class combination to apply your css or if everything fails then use javascript to apply your color property.

Comment: I am not getting any solution as i am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following CSS in your code

```
    .ui-state-highlight{     
    color: #FF0000!important;
}
```

Here just you need to use `!important` in your code.
[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/smartmkch/aVVXF/420/) for working demo

Comment: why `background:none !important`? OP wants a background

Comment: Not needed actually. so removed it and updated my answer